# Se me congela la pagina web por getboostrap

Tags: html, bootstrap, servidor, http, certificado-ssl

estoy utilizando getbootstrap para hacer mi pagina web para mi proyecto final de cs50(utilizo ide.cs50.io) y se me congela la pagina cuando utilizo **https://** pero no **http://**. Utilizo de servidor flask pero la pagina se congela cuando es segura, pienso que es Bootstrap porque es lo que utilizo para el diseño de la pagina. los formularios andan correctamente.
nose muy bien donde esta el problema pero este es mi codigo HTML, estos son los scripts de bootstrap:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
  integrity="sha384- 
 TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

aqui va mi codigo html de diseño de la pagina

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384- 
 DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384- 
9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Tu servidor tiene instalado correctamente el certificado SSL y está configurado correctamente para trabajar con `https`?

Comment: hola, si gracias ya lo solucioné, se me habían mezclado distintos códigos de jQuery y el propio Bootstrap, simplemente copie de nuevo los links de la pagina oficial de Bootstrap, sacando los scripts innecesarios.